# How to mute microphone on vue-webrtc

Tags: vue.js, webrtc, vuejs3

I’m using [vue-webrtc](https://github.com/westonsoftware/vue-webrtc) component and I want to make a button which can mute local microphone and a button to reopen local microphone.

How should I do?

I have no idea about how to do that

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here: https://github.com/westonsoftware/vue-webrtc/issues/77#issuecomment-937157711

You can get the video element (with a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs)) and call the `.mute` method on it.

Comment: What if I only want to stop sending my voice but still want to receive remote voice?

Comment: Not sure, did you Googled for that one? It's not related to `vue-webrtc` so you should get your answer for a vanilla HTML tag. @bestiantang